# Can we delete cookies of chrome/default browser in android app in case of an SSO authentication

Tags: android, cookies, browser, single-sign-on

I am trying a scenario where using app auth library for SSO authentication and this is opening the default chrome browser and facing an issue where if user is logging out and retrying login due to cookies session on webpage it is doing an auto-login where user is logged in automatically to app from SSO using cookies in SSO page and not even accepting or waiting for the credentials.